# DataDog log collection in AKS Azure Kubernetes containerd

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, datadog

I have successfully set up the DataDog agent to collect console logs from applications running in my AKS clusters where the Kubernetes version is less than 1.19.  However, I have not been able to get the agent to report logs from my new cluster which is Kubernetes 1.20.  The node agent runs without crashing, and DataDog picks up events and metrics from the cluster, but no logs.

I have followed DataDog's documentation for installing the latest version of DataDog via Helm with containerd support:

values.yaml modifications:

```
# datadog.criSocketPath -- Path to the container runtime socket (if different from Docker)
criSocketPath:  /var/run/containerd/containerd.sock

env:
    - name: DD_KUBERNETES_KUBELET_HOST
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          fieldPath: spec.nodeName
    - name: DD_KUBELET_CLIENT_CA
      value: "/host/etc/kubernetes/certs/kubeletserver.crt"

# agents.volumes -- Specify additional volumes to mount in the dd-agent container
volumes:
  - hostPath:
      path: /host/etc/kubernetes/certs/
    name: certs

# agents.volumeMounts -- Specify additional volumes to mount in all containers of the agent pod
volumeMounts:
- name: certs
  mountPath: /host/etc/kubernetes/certs/
  readOnly: true
```

I have explored the node via a privileged debug container to verify the correct location of the kubelet cert.

This is a standard AKS cluster that I just created with the Portal UI.

DataDog support has not been very helpful, acting like each situation is unique.  This AKS cluster is just out-of-the-box, as is the DataDog installation, so why am I the only one having trouble getting my logs in the new Kubernetes version?